# Sending Akka HttpEntity between actors

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-http, akka-cluster

In akka-http, `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` are mostly immutable objects, except for their `HttpEntity` bodies (which have a `Source`).

Is it safe to send a request, response, or solo entity to another actor (especially a remote actor) or is some precaution needed?

Comment: The source is bound to the lifecycle of the socket that its data is coming from. I can't imagine that passing it around to remote systems will actually work.

Comment: Also note that `Source` (and `HttpEntity`) are in fact immutable as well, therefore passing them to a local actor might work. However they are not serializable (as per @Falmarri 's comment) hence remoting won't work.

Comment: Is there a way to make it work? Either with akka-http specifically or remote sources generally? I imagine akka streaming works with remote actors, perhaps hooking that source up to a sink which can be consumed by remote streaming structures?

Comment: @kag0: Akka streams currently do not work with remote actors

Comment: @Falmarri good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments: sending an `HttpEntity` to a remote `Actor` is unlikely to work due to the socket limitation.  Further evidence can be found in [the documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/actors.html#Messages_and_immutability) (emphasis theirs):

> **IMPORTANT**: Messages can be any kind of object but have to be
>   immutable. Scala can’t enforce immutability (yet) so this has to be by
>   convention.

However, the `ByteString` values coming from the `Source` do not have the same limitations as the Source itself since ByteString is immutable.  You could simply drain the Source on the local `akka-http` ActorSystem and dispatch `ByteString` values to your remote Actor.

As an example, say you want to use an Actor to uppercase all of the characters in a utf-8 based HttpEntity.  You can setup your Actor:

```
class UpperActor extends Actor {
  override def receive : Receive = {
    case b : ByteString => sender() ! b.toString.toUpperCase
  }
}
```

Then your akka-http could look like:

```
val actorRef = ??? //setup the ref to remote UpperActor

/**Query the Actor*/
val dispatchByteString : (ByteString) => Future[String] = 
  (byteString : ByteString) => (actorRef ? byteString).mapTo[String]

val parallelism = 10 // should match your Actor's mailbox size

/**Construct the Response Source.*/
val requestToSrc : (HttpRequest) => Source[ChunkStreamPart,_] = 
  (_ : HttpRequest).entity
                   .dataBytes
                   .mapAsync(parallelism)(dispatchByteString)
                   .map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)

val contentType = ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`

val route = extractRequest { request =>
  complete(HttpResponse(entity = Chunked(contentType, requestToSrc(request))))
}
```